# External Object Related List shows timeout error

Tags: externalobjects, heroku-connect, salesforce-connect, postgres

I am trying to configure an external object in Salesforce for which the source is a Postgres table that contains approx. 34 million records.   I was able to set up the External data Source which created the external object for me. Since the table contains Case Id, I have added a look up to case in the external object. I am trying to get the records of the external object appear as a related list in Case page Layout. However I see a time out error in the related list.

This is the exact error message - 
An error occurred while connecting to the external system. Please try again, or contact your administrator. Attempted to reach this URL: https://odata-.... Error received from the external system: 530: {"detail":"Database query timed out"}

Accessing the URL directly in a browser also gives a timeout error. I tried updating the settings for the external source (unchecked RequestRowCounts and EnableSearch) but that does not seem to help.

I configured the same external object in a sandbox where we had around 8-9k records and I am able to see the related external object records.

I would appreciate any ideas on how this can be tackled.

Answer (score 0):

The Heroku table needed to have an index on the look up field which I missed creating earlier. Once the index was created, the time out issue did not reappear.